# Question on properties of Gamma functions

Tags: special-functions, gamma-function

The Gamma function has the property

$$\Gamma(z+1) = z\Gamma(z) $$

In case I have a positive real number $x$, then can I also say that:

$$ \Gamma(-x) = \frac{\Gamma(1-x)}{-x}$$

I know that $\Gamma(x)$ is not defined when $x$ is a negative integer. But is the above relation true?

Comment: What do you mean by “a negative real number $x$ such that $x>0$”?

Comment: Sorry I just mean a positive real number.

Comment: yes, in the limit, the ratio is maintained

Comment: Who says that $\Gamma(x)$ is not defined for $x<0$?

Comment: I said it is not defined for $x$ when $x$ is a negative integer. Isn't that right?

Answer (score 0):

For sure, the *integral definition* of the Gamma function is not defined for $x<0$, since the integral
$$\int_0^\infty t^{x-1}e^{-t}\mathrm dt$$
Won't converge for $x<0$. But we can extend (or *analytically continue*) this definition to these values. We know that for $x>1$, that $\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$. As long as $x$ is **not** an integer (why?) we can use the this recurrence as many times as we wish. For example, to compute $\Gamma(-1/2)$ we would write
$$\Gamma(1/2)=\Gamma(-1/2+1)=\frac{-1}{2}\Gamma(-1/2)$$
And using the well known $\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt{\pi}$ we get
$$\frac{-1}{2}\Gamma(-1/2)=\sqrt{\pi}$$
Hence
$$\Gamma(-1/2)=-2\sqrt{\pi}$$
My question to you - why does this process fail for negative integers?